# Sharing Hibernate Session between legacy HibernateTemplate code and JPA code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a quite large project developed over the years using Spring (3.2.x) + Hibernate (3.6.10) using standard LocalSessionFactoryBeanSolution.

Lately I wanted to switch to JPA over hibernate to be able to use Spring Data JPA features. This is the moment all went south. Turns out Hibernate Session resolution differs for HibernateTemplate based classes and EntityManager based clasess. I am NOT ABLE to migrate all my hibernate+hibernatetemplate code to JPA - that is simply too much work.

As one test case is more worth than 1000 words, simply put this test case fails:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test0() {
    HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate( sessionFactory );
    User user = template.execute( new HibernateCallback<User>() {
        @Override
        public User doInHibernate( Session session ) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            return (User) session.load( User.class,
                                        1l );
        }
    } );

    Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
    Assert.assertTrue( session.contains( user ) );
}
```

The only thing I was able to do is to involve some "AspectJ magic". I managed to make it all work with this aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class Hibernate2JpaMigrationFixes {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static Logger    log    = LoggerFactory.getLogger( Hibernate2JpaMigrationFixes.class );

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager        entityManager;

    @Around("execution( * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.isAllowCreate())")
    public Object disallowHibernateSessionCreation( ProceedingJoinPoint pjp ) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Around("execution( * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.clear())")
    public void disallowClear( ProceedingJoinPoint pjp ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "clear not allowed" );
    }

    @Around("execution( * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession())")
    public Object useTheSameSessionEntityManagerDoes( ProceedingJoinPoint pjp ) {
        return entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
    }
}
```

I have also tried to fiddle with hibernate.current_session_context_class - the class gets instantiated - still never used to resolve current session.

My spring + hibernate config follows:

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.MergingPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.persistence,com.xxx.smart,com.xxx.clientapp.server.model" />
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="com.mobilebox.persistence.hibernate.CustomNamingStrategy" />
            <!--
            <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext" />
             -->
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- transaction management -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect" />

<!-- legacy -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean" />
<bean id="baseHibernateDao" abstract="true" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<!-- nowe dao -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.smart.dao" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.smart.repository" />
```

Still it simply feels I am missing something. Is there anything I can do without this kind of hacking?

Comment: i've posted some possible causes, if you could try this out and post back what happened (important: please post full stacktraces with link to pastebin.com if too big)

Comment: Spring, by default, sets the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to the Spring class. If you have a persistence.xml file please post it. Basically your configuration should work. Also be aware that `session.load` doesn't do much it only constructs a proxy, whereas `session.get` actually retrieves the element from the database!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Transactional` if it's working should cause a session to be bound to the thread. Then to use the session, the template needs to be configured with some flags, try settings these flags in order to prevent the template from creating new sessions:

```
HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate( sessionFactory );

template.setAllowCreate(false);
template.setAlwaysUseNewSession(false);
```

Beware that `@Transactional` might not be working, and if so no session is being bound to the thread. in those cases each interaction with the entity manager runs in it's own session that is created and destroyed just for that query, and only detached entities are returned.

To have both things working, try to ensure the two following things are working as expected:

- `@Transactional` needs to be working, this be confirmed by setting a breakpoint in the method and checking the debug trace to see if the transactional aspect wraps the method. If so then a session is bound to the thread.
- the hibernate template needs to be configured to retrieve session from the thread, this can be confirmed to be working by setting some some breakpoints in `HibernateTemplate.getSession()`